# .js Files Transpiled From .ts Files Don't Run In Browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, browserify

I'm trying to use the h264-converter npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/h264-converter).

It is written in TypeScript.  When I run `npm install --save h264-converter` I get a folder with the .ts TypeScript files, but it also comes with the .js Javascript files in the same folder already transpiled for you.

However, the .js files it comes with do not run in a browser.  They contain `Require(...)` functions and undefined objects like `exports` that cause them not to run in a browser.  Simply including these .js files with `<script>` tags causes errors.  I did some reading and tried to use the browserify npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) to create .js files that work in a browser from .js files that don't.  I ran

`browserify "C:\...\h264-converter\dist\index.js" > "C:\...\h264-converter\dist\bundle.js"`

like the in the example on the browserfiy main page and it seemed to run without error (their example uses main.js instead of index.js but I think index.js serves the same purpose).  It created bundle.js.  However, bundle.js *still* doesn't run in a broswer.  bundle.js still has `Require(...)` functions.

How do I get the .js files that come with h264-converter npm package to run in a browser?

I can post the contents of some of the .js files that the h264-converter npm package comes with if that will help.  Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed the page https://www.npmjs.com/package/h264-converter lists the tslib npm package as a dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslib).  Luckily tslib doesn't have any further dependencies.  Will browserify work if do something with tslib?

Answer (score 0):

> npm package

To use an npm (node style commonjs) package in the browser you should use a a module bundler [like webpack](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html).